# Swift trouble parsing JSON: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' to 'NSArray' error

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I'm very new to iOS development and I have a problem to parse JSON response from an API.

Here is how my sample JSON looks like:

```
{
"recipe":{
"publisher":"Real Simple",
"f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/39999",
"ingredients":[
    "1 tablespoon olive oil",
    "1 red onion, chopped",
    "2 small yellow squash, cut into 1/2-inch pieces",
    "2 cloves garlic, chopped",
    "1 jalapeo, seeded and thinly sliced",
    "1 kosher salt and black pepper",
    "4 28-ounce can diced tomatoes\n"
],
"source_url":"http://www.realsimple.com/food-recipes/browse-all-recipes/halibut-spicy-squash-tomatoes-00000000006842/index.html",   
"recipe_id":"39999", "image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/someurl.jpg",
  "social_rank":95.14721536803285,
  "publisher_url":"http://realsimple.com",
  "title":"Halibut With Spicy Squash and Tomatoes"
  }
}
```

and when I print JSON (another one in this example) it looks like this:

```
["recipe": {
    "f2f_url" = "http://food2fork.com/view/20970";
    "image_url" = "http://static.food2fork.com/98113574b0.jpg";
    ingredients =     (
    "1 (170 gram) can crabmeat",
    "125 grams PHILADELPHIA Light Brick Cream Cheese Spread, softened",
    "2 green onions, thinly sliced",
    "1/4 cup MIRACLE WHIP Calorie-Wise Dressing",
    "12 wonton wrappers"
  );
    publisher = "All Recipes";
    "publisher_url" = "http://allrecipes.com";
    "recipe_id" = 20970;
    "social_rank" = "41.83825995815504";
    "source_url" = "http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Philly-Baked-Crab-Rangoon/Detail.aspx";
    title = "PHILLY Baked Crab Rangoon";
}]
```

I have an object Recipe and it looks like this:

```
class Recipe {
  struct Keys {
      static let Title = "title"
      static let ImageUrl = "image_url"
      static let Ingredients = "ingredients"
      static let RecipeId = "recipe_id"
  }

  var title : String? = nil
  var id = 0
  var imageUrl : String? = nil
  var ingredients : String? = nil

  init(dictionary : NSDictionary) {
      self.title = dictionary[Keys.Title] as? String
      self.id = dictionary[RecipeDB.Keys.ID] as! Int
      self.imageUrl = dictionary[Keys.ImageUrl] as? String
      self.ingredients = dictionary[Keys.Ingredients] as? String
    }
}
```

and when I try to parse JSON and cast it to a dictionary I get a `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' to 'NSArray'` error

here is my method that cast response to a dictionary and causes error

```
func recipiesFromData(data: NSData) -> [Recipe] {

    var dictionary : [String : AnyObject]!

    dictionary = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)) 
  as! [String : AnyObject]

    let recipeDictionaries = dictionary["recipe"] as! [[String : AnyObject]]

    let recipies = recipeDictionaries.map() { Recipe(dictionary: $0) }

    return recipies
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON.

Comment: That's not the original JSON. That looks like an `print` of the JSON after it's been parsed.

Comment: Why you casting nsdictionary to nsarray ?

Comment: Yes, it's a print of the JSON, I will edit my post and give another JSON example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's your JSON (a single recipe), the parsing code would look like:

```
func recipeFromData(data: NSData) -> Recipe {
    let dictionary = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])) as! [String : [String : AnyObject]]

    return Recipe(dictionary: dictionary["recipe"]!)
}
```

And I might tweak the `Recipe` class like so:

```
class Recipe {
    struct Keys {
        static let Title = "title"
        static let ImageUrl = "image_url"
        static let Ingredients = "ingredients"
        static let RecipeId = "recipe_id"
    }

    var title: String?
    var id: Int
    var imageUrl: String?
    var ingredients: [String]?

    init(dictionary : [String : AnyObject]) {
        self.title = dictionary[Keys.Title] as? String
        self.id = Int(dictionary[Keys.RecipeId] as! String)!
        self.imageUrl = dictionary[Keys.ImageUrl] as? String
        self.ingredients = dictionary[Keys.Ingredients] as? [String]
    }
}
```

That should parse the JSON.

---

Personally, I'd remove all of those `!` because if there's anything wrong, it will crash. For example:

```
enum RecipeError: ErrorType {
    case InvalidJSON(message: String, userInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject])
    case MalformedJSON
    case RecipeKeyNotFound
    case BadKeysValues
}

func recipeFromData(data: NSData) throws -> Recipe {
    var jsonObject: AnyObject

    do {
        jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
    } catch let parseError as NSError {
        throw RecipeError.InvalidJSON(message: parseError.localizedDescription, userInfo: parseError.userInfo)
    }

    guard let dictionary = jsonObject as? [String : AnyObject] else {
        throw RecipeError.MalformedJSON
    }

    guard let recipeDictionary = dictionary["recipe"] as? [String: AnyObject] else {
        throw RecipeError.RecipeKeyNotFound
    }

    guard let recipe = Recipe(dictionary: recipeDictionary) else {
        throw RecipeError.BadKeysValues
    }

    return recipe
}
```

Whether you go to this extreme is just a question of what sort of errors you want to be able to capture gracefully, but hopefully this illustrates the point, that you want to avoid using forced unwrapping (with `!` or `as!`) if dealing with data that you're getting from a remote source which might introduce problems that your app must anticipate and handle gracefully rather than just crashing.

By the way, in the above example, I gave `Recipe` a failable initializer:

```
struct Recipe {
    struct Keys {
        static let Title = "title"
        static let ImageUrl = "image_url"
        static let Ingredients = "ingredients"
        static let RecipeId = "recipe_id"
    }

    let title: String?
    let id: Int
    let imageUrl: String?
    let ingredients: [String]?

    init?(dictionary : [String : AnyObject]) {
        if let idString = dictionary[Keys.RecipeId] as? String, let id = Int(idString) {
            self.id = id
        } else {
            return nil
        }
        self.title = dictionary[Keys.Title] as? String
        self.imageUrl = dictionary[Keys.ImageUrl] as? String
        self.ingredients = dictionary[Keys.Ingredients] as? [String]
    }
}
```

(Note, I've made this a `struct`, as it supports more intuitive failable initializers. If you want a failable initializer for a class, it requires that you initialize everything before you fail (which seems counter intuitive to me).

Answer (score 0):

Here's valid JSON, which perfectly converts to `[String : AnyObject]`

```
let string = "{\"recipe\":{\"f2f_url\":\"http://food2fork.com/view/20970\",\"image_url\":\"http://static.food2fork.com/98113574b0.jpg\",\"ingredients\":[\"1 (170 gram) can crabmeat\",\"125 grams PHILADELPHIA Light Brick Cream Cheese Spread, softened\",\"2 green onions, thinly sliced\",\"1/4 cup MIRACLE WHIP Calorie-Wise Dressing\",\"12 wonton wrappers\"],\"publisher\":\"All Recipes\",\"publisher_url\":\"http://allrecipes.com\",\"recipe_id\":20970,\"social_rank\":\"41.83825995815504\",\"source_url\":\"http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Philly-Baked-Crab-Rangoon/Detail.aspx\",\"title\":\"PHILLY Baked Crab Rangoon\"}}"

do{
  let dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
  print(dict)
} catch let error as NSError{
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```